# How can I search for a string in a string?

Tags: string

Is can I search for a string in a string?
I stored the source code of a page and now I have to search for various stings (stored in parameters) within the code.
Is there a command I can use?

Thanks

Comment: in which language? :-/

Comment: Using what? C#? Java? PHP? Pig latin? Sign language? Wingdings?!

Comment: We aren't mind readers.

Comment: yes, the language would really help. Most languages have some kind of function for that, eg. `strpos(string, searchstring)` in PHP

Comment: Please specify which language. Make sure you provide all information regarding question before posting it

Answer (score 4):

Open the source code in Notepad

Hit Ctrl-F

Type string to search